# Illegal Instruction: 4 in C-program

Tags: c, macos

I'm a complete beginner in C, and currently working through the exercises in the C Programming Language-book by Kernighan and Ritchie. This particular exercise is 1.13, where I'm trying to make a program that outputs a histogram based on the lengths of the words inputted. However, when compiling and running this piece of code, I receive the following error after hitting Enter in the console:

Illegal Instruction: 4

The code itself is definitely faulty and incomplete, but I was simply trying to test it here. The problem is I cannot figure out where this error is coming from. I'm using a Macbook and have tried to specify my OS-version during compilation to gcc, without this helping the problem.

```
#define WORD 0
#define NONWORD 1

int main(void)
{
  int c, i, j;
  int state;
  int incrementer;
  /* This solution only works for word-lengths below 20 characters.
    Can be expanded/decreased by resizing wordLengths-array to any given length. */
  int wordLengths[20];
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n'){
        state = NONWORD;
    } else {
      state = WORD;
    }
    if (state == WORD) {
      incrementer++;
    }
    if (state == NONWORD && incrementer != 0) {
      wordLengths[incrementer-'1']++;
      incrementer = 0;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(wordLengths); i++) {
    printf("%d |", i);
    for (j = 0; j < wordLengths[i]; j++) {
      putchar('=');
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("Hello world");
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling it on the same MacBook or on some other machine? How are you compiling?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Of course. I'll email it to you.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes. But you will have to go to an Apple store and buy it :)

Comment: @EugeneSh Same MacBook

Comment: then show the gcc invocation

Comment: @user4612744 Sounds Cool!! ok, I'll do one thing then, I'll mail you to ask your mail ID, and after I get, I'll do the answer. :P

Comment: `i` should be `size_t`

Comment: Well, `incrementer` is uninitialized. Is a simple "hello world" program working with the same compillation steps?

Comment: @EugeneSh. gcc -mmacosx-version-min=10.10  -o ex113 exercise1-13.c

Comment: Automatic storage 'incrementer' is used without initialization:(

Comment: ...aaand it's used an an array index: 'wordLengths[incrementer-'1']++;', mucho UB for you-hoo!

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've been successfully doing all the exercises up until this one, so yep. First time running into this problem.

Comment: So fix the code. It's not about the compiler.

Comment: `incrementer-'1'` is UB. It is equal to `incrementer-0x31` or `incrementer-49` So you are accessing your array with negative indexes.

Comment: @MartinJames Whoops... I fixed it and it's working.

Comment: @LPs thanks for the heads up. Probably why it got caught in an endless loop just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugger is your best friend. You would immediately realize that your `incrementer` isn't enough for counting which word is it at, or for being used as your array's index.
One of the possibilities would be to introduce a separate variable for counting words and writing measured length to corresponding member of your array

```
int wcnt = -1;
```

in the following way:

```
        if (state == WORD) {
            if(incrementer == 0)wcnt++;
            incrementer++;
        }
        if (state == NONWORD && incrementer != 0) {
            wordLengths[wcnt] = incrementer;
            incrementer = 0;
        }
```

and also use it for `printf()`ing the written sizes from the array members:

```
for (i = 0; i <= wcnt; i++){ … }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is absolutely correct. I misunderstood the exercise a little and developed a program that printed out number of instances of different word-lengths instead.